# How can Elasticsearch search characters like %?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need a search for a value, for example `100%`, and I have documents with, for example, the text `"100% guarantee"`
Instead, it finds according to the LIKE principle of `100%`, that is, in hits highlights only digit (100, 1002, 100-500, 500-100 ....)

query:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "100%",
      "type": "phrase_prefix", 
      "fields": ["title", "body"]
    }
  },
  "size": 5
  }
```

and i try:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "body",
      "query": "100%",
      "allow_leading_wildcard": false
    }
  },
  "size": 5,
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "body": {
        "type": "plain",
        "fragment_size": 20,
        "pre_tags": "<span class='bold'>",
        "post_tags": "</span>", 
        "number_of_fragments": 1
      }
    }
  }
  }
```

example First highlight:

```
"highlight" : {
          "body" : [
            "-<span class='bold'>100</span> - you number"
          ]
        }
```

Comment: can you please share your sample index data, and expected search result? And what do you mean by **only documents with clean digits.**, can you please explain this?

Comment: sry. im update qyestion

Comment: so you want to highlight `100%` and not just `100` ?

Comment: im wont  to If query have "%" or another special symbol not ignir him

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Answer (score 1):

**In the highlighted query, only the digit is highlighted and not the special characters, this is because of the `standard` analyzer. Since, you have not defined any analyzer, for your `title` field, so the standard analyzer is the default analyzer which is used if none is specified.**

```
GET/_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "100% guarantee"
}
```

Following tokens are generated:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "100",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "guarantee",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see that Elasticsearch's standard analyzer just strips the "%" character. The analyzer is applied at index time so your text never makes it into the index as you want it.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Analyze API:**

```
GET/_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "my_analyzer",
  "text" : "100% guarantee"
}
```

Following tokens are generated:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "100%",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "guarantee",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "title": "100% guarantee"
}
{
  "title": "100 guarantee"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "title",
      "query": "100%",
      "allow_leading_wildcard": false
    }
  },
  "size": 5,
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "title": {
        "type": "plain",
        "fragment_size": 20,
        "pre_tags": "<span class='bold'>",
        "post_tags": "</span>",
        "number_of_fragments": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64608747",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.6931471,
        "_source": {
          "title": "100% guarantee"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "title": [
            "<span class='bold'>100%</span> guarantee"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Shevtsov Eugene did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: @Shevtsov Eugene it's been a long time. I hope you are doing well :) If you don't have any follow-up questions and if my answer helped you resolve your issue, then please dont forget to upvote and accept my answer :)